# How to Speed Up Performance of ISpVoice?

Tags: c++, winapi, sapi

I am trying to build a game menu that reads the highlighted text using ISpVoice and keyboard.

My problem is that there is a delay whenever I change the highlighted text using the keyboard. This only happens when I use ISpVoice.

```
tts->Speak(myWstring.c_str(), SPF_PURGEBEFORESPEAK | SPF_ASYNC, 0);
```

I tried the above code but still there is a lag.

```
tts->Speak(myWstring.c_str(), SPF_ASYNC, 0);
```

the above code works but I want it to immediate stop whenever I want to change the highlighted text.

Comment: Have you tried calling `ISpVoice::Pause()` before speaking new text?

Comment: I tried calling the functions but it resumes only when `ISpVoice::Resume()` is called. It goes silent if ISpVoice::Pause() is only called.

Comment: So, `Pause()`'ing the current voice, `Speak()`'ing the new text with purge, and then `Resume()`'ing doesn't work?

Comment: I tried it. Performance is better but it still lags when the tts almost finishes the sentence.

Comment: I think it lags when the thread finishes.

Comment: @AlzerCasiño Have you tried debugging to check the lag happens before or after the call of tts->Speak()?

Comment: I cannot tell because it runs asynchronously but I noticed that it only lags when the thread of tts->Speak finishes.

Comment: @AlzerCasiño You can [check the time](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/sysinfoapi/nf-sysinfoapi-getsystemtime) to show the actual time and your expect time and show how much the lag is.

Answer (score 0):

You could purge previous speech tasks using the SVSFPurgeBeforeSpeak flag in the [SpeechVoiceSpeakFlags](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms720892(v=vs.85)) enumeration.

```
tts->Speak(myWstring.c_str(), SVSFlagsAsync | SVSFPurgeBeforeSpeak, 0);
```

Or:

```
tts->Speak(myWstring.c_str(), 1 | 2, 0);
```

That will clean (purge) all previous asynchronous speech tasks without any lag.